# how to send information to page

Tags: html, iframe

My website consists mainly of pages that are loaded into an iframe on the homepage. 
When the pages are loaded they check if they have been opened outside the iframe and if they are the homepage is opened.

Now I want to open this specific page when the homepage is opened. 
How do I send the information that the "browser came from" test.html? And then set the source of the iframe to be `test.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax

```
top.document.referrer
```

will let you access the parent of the iFrame;

```
document.getElementById('myIframeId').src = myUrl + 'test.html';
```

will set the iFrame source.

Comment: I have this code in test.html, and I want to send the value "test.html" to displayiframe.php
'
<?php
$src_url_iframe = "test.html"; 
$_SESSION["iframesource_url"] = $src_url_iframe;
?>'

Answer (score 0):

Pass the URL of the page to be framed in the query string of the URL to the page containing the frame.